# Going through Python Crash Course book. Running code on A Class to Test and encountering undefined variable error

Tags: variables, undefined

I'm currently going through the book and am going through this part that is provided:

```
def __init__(self,question):
    self.question = question
    self.responses = []
```

and the following code further down is being flagged by undefined variable.

```
def show_question(self):
    print(question)
```

Comment: Because you're not referring to **`self.`** `question`...

Comment: You've asked for the local variable "question" which doesn't exist in show_question().  Try print(self.question) instead.